# In London, what information can I get about an apartment based on location (postcode)?

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation, accommodation

I'm currently looking for an apartment in London and it occurred to me that there are websites that can provide information for tenants-to-be about a specific location or area based on postcode (or general location) alone.

What information can I find out about a potential future apartment based on its location (postcode), in regards to bills and other expenses and quality of life overall?

Comment: Some of the online property websites will pull in lots of this data and display it for you. You can also get stuff about public transport, nearby shops and restaurants etc

Answer (score 3):

Some websites that contain useful information and have a postcode-based search:

- [Crystal Roof](https://crystalroof.co.uk) - research tool with postcode granularity. Demographics, affluence, crime, noise, flooding, etc presented as a summary and via heatmaps. Also, users can leave reviews on postcodes they know.
- [StreetCheck](https://www.streetcheck.co.uk/) provides some good info about the area, in terms of housing types, demographics, crime, broadband quality and others.
- [Check My Postcode](http://checkmypostcode.uk) similarly provides street view, census information and a short summary.
- [Check Postcode](https://www.checkpostcode.uk)  provides a summary of census information, broadband speeds, sold house prices transport availability and schools data.
- [mycounciltax.org.uk](http://www.mycounciltax.org.uk/) can show the Council Tax amount for a given postcode.
- [Metropolitan Police](http://maps.met.police.uk/) provides crime rate per area.
- [uSwitch](https://www.uswitch.com/broadband/) and [broadband.co.uk](http://www.broadband.co.uk/) seem to provide information about internet providers for a given postcode.
- [London Air](http://www.londonair.org.uk/) displays realtime pollution levels per location.
- [Locrating](http://www.locrating.com/) shows the nearest schools (with ratings).
- [Quicksold](https://quicksold.co.uk/area-information) Housing information, residential data, crime statistics, sold house prices along with wealth and other ranks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget good old Google Street View to check the area with your own eyes. Google maps will also show you nearby public transport facilities, and to a limited extent, shops, restaurants etc.

Just go to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps), enter "London + postal code" like [London W6 7LU](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Shepherds+Bush+Rd,+London+W6+7LU,+UK/@51.5009358,-0.2243249,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x48760fc5be7540e3:0xe36575eb574e433c!8m2!3d51.5008213!4d-0.2217039):

[image]

Then click on that bottom left picture to enter Street View:

[image]